# how do I fetch chart from Kubernetes cluster ? not from repository

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have k8s cluster installed with tiller and many charts , how can I download and view the charts installed on existing cluster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not download the whole chart from your Kubernetes cluster, as it only stores 
the applied resources, with already replaced values. Instead, you can download the release with **helm get** command.

`helm get [flags] RELEASE_NAME`

> This command shows the details of a named release.
>
> It can be used to get extended information about the release,
>   including:
>
> The values used to generate the release The chart used to generate the
>   release The generated manifest file By default, this prints a human
>   readable collection of information about the chart, the supplied
>   values, and the generated manifest file.

[Documentation](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/helm/helm_get.md#helm-get)

Comment: Thanks that has helped to find solutions